# macro inserts the word TRUE in cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that moves worksheets to the end of a workbook with several worksheets if a value in a cell range is X or empty. When this macro runs, I have it start at a certain sheet that is inputted. It also checks to see if the name of the inputted sheet is valid. If it is, it then checks for the X or empty cell. The macro works except it puts the word "TRUE" in the each sheet that does not have the X or empty cell. See ***'INSERTS THE WORD "TRUE" HERE*** in the code where it happens.

Where is the word "TRUE" coming from? And how do I stop it from putting it in?

```
Sub Move_X_CodeSheets_to_end()
    'This macro will take any X type sheets and put them at the end of the
    'sheets
    'so they are not printed when the file in turned into a pdf and submitted.
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sp As Integer
    Dim SheetPick As String
    Dim s As Integer, SheetFound As Boolean

    Do
        SheetPick = InputBox("Enter the case sensitive sheet name to start sorting with")
        If SheetPick = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

        SheetFound = False 'SheetFound must be set to False initially

        With ThisWorkbook
            For s = 1 To Sheets.Count
                If Sheets(s).Name = SheetPick Then
                    SheetFound = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next s
        End With
        If SheetFound = False Then
            MsgBox(SheetPick & " Doesn't exist!", vbExclamation)
        Else
        End If
    Loop Until SheetFound = True

    Sheets(SheetPick).Select()
    sp = Sheets(SheetPick).Index

    For i = sp To Sheets.Count
        Cells(i, 1) = Sheets(i).Select

        'INSERTS THE WORD "TRUE" HERE

        Range("D7").Select()

        'if X type code, then move sheet to end
        If ActiveCell.Value = "X" Then
            ActiveSheet.Move After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        End If

        'if cell is empty, then move sheet to end
        If ActiveCell.Value = Empty Then
            ActiveSheet.Move After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        End If

    Next i

Done:
    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: It is because of the line `Cells(i, 1) = Sheets(i).Select` To understand what that line does, type this in the Immediate window `?Sheets(1).Select=true`

Comment: `Sheets(i).Select` will always return TRUE (providing you can select that sheet - otherwise it will throw an error), and you're telling it to put the result of that into column A, row i.

In the immediate window type `?Sheets(1).Select` it will return TRUE.

Comment: I'm going to starting waiting a bit longer Siddharth - you're always beating me to the reply. :)

Comment: @Siddarth and @Darren. Thank you. That worked. I don't understand what you mean by "type this in the Immediate window `?Sheets(1).Select=true`" What is the "immediate window?". I typed `?Sheets(1).Select=true` on the next line after `Cells(i, 1) = Sheets(i).Select` and the ? turned to Print and I get a compile error.

Comment: Press Ctrl+G while in the Visual Basic window and a pane will appear at the bottom called 'Immediate'.
Anything you type in here is executed immediately.  The question mark is the Print command - tells it to show the result in the Immediate window.  
I find it handy when I've interrupted my code and can't manually interact with the worksheets (i.e. change the active sheet / workbook).  The Immediate window will allow you to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code assigns the result of ' Sheets(i).Select' to 'Cells(i, 1)'.

If you change

```
Cells(i, 1) = Sheets(i).Select
```

to just

```
Sheets(i).Select
```

it should work.

However, for performance and clarity reasons you should strive to avoid .select. For instance instead of

```
Sheets(i).Select
Range("D7").Select
If ActiveCell.Value = "X" Then
   ActiveSheet.Move After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
End If
```

you could write

```
If Sheets(i).Range("D7").Value = "X" Then
   Sheets(i).Move After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
End If
```

which is faster and easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks @burtelli. I used this in hopes it would fix another problem this macro has. The workbook has 298 sheets. I start looking at sheet 10 (usually) for the X or empty cells. It goes through the whole workbook and moves most, but not all sheets with the X or empty cell in D7. If I run it again and again, it will eventually get them all, then I sort the sheets since they are now out of order alphanumerically. Why do you think it misses some sheets with X or empty cell D7's?

Comment: that happens because you're are iterating over the index while moving sheets around. imagine the simple case of having 3 sheets:
you literate from sheet index 1 to 3. sheet 1 fulfills your criteria and gets moved to the end. your original sheet 2 now has the index of 1 which has already been checked and will therefore not be considered. i=2 now refers to your original sheet 3 and i=3 is the sheet that has just been moved. 
to avoid this try iterating backwards: for i=sheets.count to 1 step -1

Comment: It was grey and then turned green when I clicked on it. Thank you Siddharth Rout, Darren Bartrup-Cook and burtelli , I learned a little from each of you.